# How to deal with pySpark structured streaming coming from Kafka to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using pyspark to get data from Kafka and inserting it into cassandra. I'm almost there i just need the final step.

```py
def Spark_Kafka_Receiver():

# STEP 1 OK!

    dc = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "000.00.0.240:9092") \
        .option("subscribe", "MyTopic") \
    .load()
    dc.selectExpr("CAST(key as STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING) as msg")

# STEP 2 OK!

    dc.writeStream \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function) \
        .start() \
        .awaitTermination()

# STEP 3 NEED HELP

def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
    Value = df.select(df.value)

    ???????

    # WRITE DATA FRAME ON CASSANDRA
    df.write \
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
        .mode('append') \
        .options(table=table_name, keyspace=keyspace) \
        .save()
```

So i have my Value that is in this format:

DataFrame[value: binary]

i would need to insert something that open my Value take the binary inside and create a nice dataframe with the correct format that mach the database and with it execute the last part of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `foreachBatch` anymore.  You just need to upgrade to Spark Cassandra Connector 2.5 that natively supports Spark Structured Streaming, so you can just write:

```py
dc.writeStream \
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
        .mode('append') \
        .options(table=table_name, keyspace=keyspace)
        .start() \
        .awaitTermination()
```

Regarding the second part of your question - if you want to convert your value into a multiple columns, you need to use `from_json` function, passing the schema to it.  Here is example in Scala, but Python code should be quite similar:

```scala
val schemaStr = "id:int, value:string"
val schema = StructType.fromDDL(schemaStr)
val data = dc.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .select(from_json($"value", schema).as("data"))
  .select("data.*").drop("data")
```

and then you can write that data via `writeStream`

Comment: From my kafka producer I'm sending a string, I'm thinking that maybe at this point it would be better to create the JSON from there so the consumer would find already the message in JSON format. How does it sounds, do you think that it makes more sense convert it before sending? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Kafka doesn't care about types - it works with binary data. So how you encode the data is your responsibility on both sides.  I described the JSON because I saw cast to string in your code.